# Unit testing with async methods

Tags: unit-testing

I am having a trouble testing async methods. What is the correct way to test asynchronous methods, unit test and integration test wise?

I heard about test doubles, what could that mean from async perspective?

Comment: Do you have any code samples to show what sort of object/methods you are trying to test?

Answer (score 0):

For async methods that hit…

- A networked resource
- A filesystem
- A database

…For unit tests, replace these with test doubles. Think "stunt double," because they're temporarily standing in for the real thing. We do this for unit tests because these resources are unreliable, persistent (which causes tests to affect each other), or slow. By slow, I mean a unit test should take no more than 100 milliseconds.

Other async methods that *aren't* to such resources can be unit tested. Put them in a polling loop with a timeout. This is also how things like networking can be done in integration tests, or contract tests (which check that real communication and faked communication match).

Comment: Also, if you're testing something that hits something external (network, filesystem, database) this is more of an integration test than unit test. A unit test should test part of your system in isolation - mock out the exernals to return expected data. You should also have your mocks return exceptions/invalid data to check these are also handled.